# How to display an image for a short duration on a button click in android?

Tags: android, android-button

*i  am  developing  an  android  app.* what  i  need  to  do  is  when  i  click  on  a  button  i  want  to  display  an  image  for  a  short  duration  then  return  back  to  the  menu.  Can  anyone  pls  guide  me  in  it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be [creating a custom Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView).

[image: Toast]

Answer (score 0):

Toggle the visibility of the image and start a thread and toggle it back at the end of the thread. Want some code?